# How to make the iPhone top ToolBar backGroundColor(gray -> black): time, battery life

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

How to make the iPhone top ToolBar backGroundColor change from gray to black?

How do I do this programmatically?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is in your Info.plist for your application.

The key is "Status bar style".

Also, here's how to do it programatically:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

I hope this helps.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];
```